# #REF! pasted as value, but not seen as such when looping

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I just released an Excel Add-In in my department today that I've been working on for the last 2+ months that checks for about 30 validation errors. I have the error trapping handled in all situations (as it appears right now), but I received a horrible wake-up call today as I received automatic emails (a feature I built into the error handling) for two vital bugs. I already posted a question about the first bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711450/how-can-i-work-around-the-findwhat-character-limitation-in-excel-vba) and figured I'd start a fresh question for the second bug as it's about something unrelated to the first.

My code is as follows

```
Private Sub symbolCheck()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.StatusBar = "(3/16) Checking for invalid symbols"

Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim replacementsMade As Boolean
replacementsMade = False
MyArray = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    For j = LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)
        If MyArray(i, j) <> "" Then
            'Apostrophe/Closing Single Quote
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "’") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "’", Chr(39))
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Apostrophe
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "`") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "`", Chr(39))
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Opening Single Quote
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "‘") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "‘", Chr(39))
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Double Open Quotes
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "“") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "“", """")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Double Closing Quotes
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "”") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "”", """")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Dash
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "–") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "–", "-")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Registered Trademark (R)
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "®") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "®", "(R)")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Trademark (TM)
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "™") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "™", "(TM)")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Degree Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "°") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "°", " degrees")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Multiplication/x Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "×") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "×", "x")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Upside-Down Question Mark Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "¿") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "¿", "")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Solid Bullet Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "•") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "•", "")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Triple Dots Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "…") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "…", "...")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Euro Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "€") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "€", "")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Linebreak Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "|") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "|", ",")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
'            'Less Than Symbol
'            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "<") > 0 Then
'                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "<", "<")
'            End If
'            'Greater Than Symbol
'            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), ">") > 0 Then
'                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), ">", ">")
'            End If
            'Half Fraction
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "½") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "½", " 1/2")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Three Quarter Fraction
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "¾") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "¾", " 3/4")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'One Quarter Fraction
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "¼") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "¼", " 1/4")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

If replacementsMade Then
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange = MyArray
End If

Set MyArray = Nothing

Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "symbolCheck", Err.Description
End Sub
```

This bug occurs on the line

```
If MyArray(i, j) <> "" Then
```

When *i* = 209 and *j* = 60, so I did some poking around and looked inside the array to see what value was at that location. The value just says `Error 2023` when I looked at the Watchlist values for the array slot. So, I looked at the cell that corresponded with those *i* and *j* values and alas I finally saw why the error was raised. The value in the cell was originally a formula with reference errors and since I copy/pasted as values prior to running this sub I thought I'd be fine. I had no idea that `#REF!` wasn't seen as plaintext?

**Which leads me to my question**

How can I handle this situation? More precisely, how would I be able to get rid of the `#REF!` values in a spreadsheet (without using Find/Replace) if `#REF!` isn't seen as plaintext even after being Copy/Pasted as a value?

Comment: `#REF!` <> "" so it appears your if statement is working fine?

Comment: No, that line is where the error occurs when the value being checked is `#REF`. It should go through the code within the if statement if it were seen as text, just like everything else has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution to Clear #REF! Values in Spreadsheet**

You can use SpecialCells to clear the errors.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).ClearContents 'Or change .Value to another value, delete cells, etc. as desired
```

**Solution to handle #REF! Errors in Array**

You can use the ISERROR() VBA function to capture each #REF! and then handle as desired.

Modify your code as follows:

```
Private Sub symbolCheck()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.StatusBar = "(3/16) Checking for invalid symbols"

Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim replacementsMade As Boolean
replacementsMade = False
MyArray = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    For j = LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)
        If IsError(MyArray(i, j)) Then
            'Handle the #REF! here

        ElseIf MyArray(i, j) <> "" Then
            'Apostrophe/Closing Single Quote
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "’") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "’", Chr(39))
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Apostrophe
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "`") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "`", Chr(39))
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Opening Single Quote
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "‘") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "‘", Chr(39))
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Double Open Quotes
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "“") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "“", """")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Double Closing Quotes
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "”") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "”", """")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Dash
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "–") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "–", "-")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Registered Trademark (R)
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "®") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "®", "(R)")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Trademark (TM)
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "™") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "™", "(TM)")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Degree Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "°") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "°", " degrees")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Multiplication/x Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "×") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "×", "x")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Upside-Down Question Mark Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "¿") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "¿", "")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Solid Bullet Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "•") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "•", "")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Triple Dots Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "…") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "…", "...")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Euro Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "€") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "€", "")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Linebreak Symbol
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "|") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "|", ",")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
'            'Less Than Symbol
'            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "<") > 0 Then
'                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "<", "<")
'            End If
'            'Greater Than Symbol
'            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), ">") > 0 Then
'                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), ">", ">")
'            End If
            'Half Fraction
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "½") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "½", " 1/2")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'Three Quarter Fraction
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "¾") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "¾", " 3/4")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
            'One Quarter Fraction
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "¼") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "¼", " 1/4")
                If replacementsMade = False Then
                    replacementsMade = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

If replacementsMade Then
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange = MyArray
End If

Set MyArray = Nothing

Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "symbolCheck", Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect! I'm glad there was at least some simple way to handle this. Thank you! I'm still perplexed though about `#REF!` not being seen as plain text. I even put just a plain `#` in a cell to see if maybe Excel's programmed to still look at the statements starting with `#` differently (because they typically are different and significant in cases other than this). I'll accept your answer when the 10-minute minimum wait is up.